# installation issue of ggplot2 in R 4.0

Tags: r

I tried to install ggplot2 in R studio (R version 4.0) windows. I ran R studio as admin but I got this following error

Error in install.packages: cannot open file 'C:/Users/R/win-library/4.0/file4e88623a5458/ps/bin/i386/interrupt.exe': Permission denied

Can anybody help, please

Thank you,
nitin

Comment: can you open Rx64 with admin rights and try to install by  install.packages("ggplot2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you will have less issues running R from command line when you want to upgrade or install large chunk of packages. Best is to run `R --vanilla` command to do administrative work on your **R ecosystem**.